# Storing object data to .csv file from async function of nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im working with one nodejs module. I want to store entire array data to .csv file in one-go. Im using [this external csv writer] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvdata) module.

Here data is coming from server at interval of 1 sec. i'm storing that data to array object. i want to store data to csv file in one go. (Say 5 records at a time.)

blank .csv file is created!

```
var http = require("http");
var csvData = require("csvdata");

arrayeachen = [];
v = 0;
function request() {
    var v = 0;
    http.get("http://localhost:1234/server", function (res) {
        res.on('data', function (data) {
            pushdata(data);
        });

    });
}

function pushdata(data) {
    if (v < 5){
        arrayeachen.push(data);
        v++;
    }
    else {
        WriteToCSVFile(arrayeachen.toString())
    }
}

function WriteToCSVFile(pro) {
    console.log('Log ',pro);
    csvData.write("./my-csv.csv",pro,{header:'name,roll,value,aqaa,vdddd'});
}


setInterval(request, 1000);
```

Comment: what does `console.log('Log ',pro)` print ?

Comment: Also I think you want to set `v=0` in your else block

Comment: [ { name: 'chinmay', roll: '2', value: 'Value of Code!' },
  { name: 'chinmay', roll: '2', value: 'Value of Code!' },
  { name: 'chinmay', roll: '2', value: 'Value of Code!' },
  { name: 'chinmay', roll: '2', value: 'Value of Code!' } ]

Comment: try putting the content of function `WriteToSCVFile` inside a try catch and see if any error is obtained